# MacBook (12” 2017) – Bluetooth not available

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

I've an bluetooth issue with a MacBook 12'' (2017): bluetooth is not available anymore. The bluetooth icon in the menu bar is greyed out and strikethrough.

I've reset already SMC and PRAM/NVRAM (followed the instructions found in the Apple help pages) and although deleted the file `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist`, but without any success.

Finally, I run the Mac diagnostics tool which don't find any error, quitting with code ADP000 (see. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203747).

The MacBook runs currently Mojave and I do not trust myself to upgrade to Catalina, fearing upgrade problems due to the missing bluetooth.

Any help is very welcome!